# Is this function from lpmj.net distorting the image?

Tags: php, image

```
  if ($typeok)
    {
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);   
    $tw  = $w;
    $th  = $h;
    $max = 100; 
    if($w > $h && $max < $w)
      {
      $th = $max / $w * $h;     
      $tw = $max;
      }
    elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)   
      {
      $tw = $max / $h * $w;     
      $th = $max;
      }
    elseif ($max < $w)  
      {
      $tw = $th = $max; 
      }
      $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);    
      imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
      imageconvolution($tmp, array(array(-1, -1, -1), array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
      imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto); 
      imagedestroy($tmp);
      imagedestroy($src);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final condition should only be executed in the case that $h = $w and both are > $max.

The first condition fires only when $w is bigger than $h and it needs to be resized. The second will only fire if $h is bigger than $w, and the image needs to be resized. So, the third condition merely checks to see if the image needs to be resized ($w > $max). If it does, you can safely assume that $w = $h because neither of the previous 2 conditions fired (meaning, $w was not bigger, and $h wasn't bigger. They must be equal).

The only remaining conditions involved ones where $w and $h are less than $max. No resizing needs to be done here, so we don't bother catching those conditions.

Hope that makes sense!